# JavaScript "for (var i = 0; ...) { ... }" browser incompatibilities?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cross-browser

I haven't done serious JavaScript programming in a while, and I am writing an intro guide to the language for some of my colleagues. I'd like to discuss loop best practices, but there is one small detail I've kept in the back of my head:

When looping over arrays, I remember the following pattern not being safe to use because there are major browsers that don't support it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) { ... }
```

Instead, the var keyword must be moved out of the array, as such:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) { ... }
```

Is this correct? I've scoured the net and cannot confirm this. Do some old browsers not support the first method? If not, which ones do not?

Comment: I, personally, can't think of any browser where the first example would fail.

Comment: No browsers in common use in 2012 fail to support either of those.  They're exactly the same. (When I say "common use" I mean used by more than one or two outlying cases; maybe somebody's running Netscape 3 somewhere, but you get the picture. And Netscape 3 probably worked.)

Comment: how old are you looking to get?  Are we talking Netscape and IE3 or are you referring to IE7 timeframe?

Comment: In the (admittedly not that long) time I've been coding with Javascript, I don't recall coming across any problems when using the first method. What versions of which browsers are you looking to support? Shouldn't be too difficult to test if you have access to all of them.

Comment: Also, before you knock yourself out on this project, the amount of good-quality JavaScript tutorial information on the web is incredible. There are literally thousands of such tutorials out there, as well as numerous up-to-date books.

Comment: I have been coding this since 1996 in IE3.02 and NS2.x it would work just fine

Comment: @Pointy, Jeff V: I am definitely not covering any territory before IE7, if that. This is meant to be a cursory guide tailored to our use cases as a (primarily) mobile app company. Most of our code is written for mobile Webkit implementations; I just want to make sure I have my facts straight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *"Is this correct?"*

Unless we're talking about some really, really old browser, I'm not aware of any such issue with browsers in use today.

---

The only issue people likely have with the first example is that it may confuse someone into thinking that JavaScript has *block scope*, which it doesn't **This changed since ES6, which does have block scope**.

In either example, the `i` variable will be scoped to the enclosing variable environment, whether the enclosing environment is a function, or the global environment.

Answer (score 7):

> Instead, the var keyword must be moved out of the array

Not necessarily. The point is that you should NOT forget `var` keyword before `i` otherwise it will turn into **global** variable. So it is fine if you do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) { ... }
```

You can improve the **performance** of above code by creating a variables that holds that length of the array/collection rather than reading it again and again with each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0, len = ls.length; i < len; i++) { ... }
```

---

BTW don't worry about browser, that loop should work across browsers :)

Comment: Off-topic, but this isn't the first time I've heard that storing the length in a variable is an important optimization. What is the browser doing under the hood? I'd think that .length should be a constant time lookup, not something that is calculated, ever.

Comment: @thebossman: In JavaScript, everything is an object. In the loop the array you use is also an object. While in the loop, its value is read again and again with each iteration eg JS accesses array's property with each iteration which takes more time than creating a variable and assigning length to it. Of course, for most users or apps, this isn't much of issue but for performance-oriented or massive apps, it becomes crucial step.

Comment: @thebossman: Yes, but you have to look it up often. Storing it in a local variable means even faster access.

Comment: @Safraz So the property access is what's expensive? Sounds like the interpreter/compiler should optimize this. Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not supporting any browsers older than IE6, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Nor in IE 3.02 nor Netscape 2.0

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript actually declares function level scope not block scope. Declared variables are hoisted to the top of their function. What I'm saying is your examples are actually identical. Even with the `var` keyword within the `for` statement, the `i` variable will be accessible outside the loop.

The only thing you have to look out for is if you omit the `var` the variable will be global instead of confined to the function.

Answer (score 0):

bumped into this today

```
   for(var i=0; i < t; i++) {
//do whatever
}
```

my jscript was in an xsl file called from an html file - worked fine in IE, but not on other browsers - code would crash and nothing displayed

fortunately I could change it to, which worked for all tested browsers

```
for(var i=0; i != t; i++) {
do whatever}
```

also be aware of
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/273793/how-to-include-client-side-script-functions-in-an-xsl-document

Answer (score -1):

Not that you asked for it, but you can use jQuery to do this as follows:

```
$.each(ls, function(i,value){
...
});
```